# Detecting a smaller image (.png) within a larger image retrieved with ImageGrab?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I've spent the past hour researching this simple topic, but all of the answers I've come across have been very complex and, as a noob to Python, I've been unable to incorporate any of them into my program.

I am trying to make an AI play a browser version of the Piano Tiles Game. As of now, I'm simply trying to take a capture of the games window (a small portion of my computer screen), and then check that games window with a .png of the game's start button. From there I will go on to CLICK that start button, but that's a problem for another time.

***How can I check to see if a Image contains a .png file?***

Here is my current code:

```
from PIL import ImageGrab as ig, ImageOps as io, Image
import pyautogui
import bbox

def grabStart(window):
    #The start button
    start = Image.open("res/StartButton.PNG")
    start = io.grayscale(start)

    #This is the part I need to figure out. The following is just pseudocode
    if window.contains(start): #I know that this doesn't actually work. Just pseudocode
        #I'd like to return the location of 'start' in one of the following forms
        return either: (x1, y1, x2, y2), (x1, y1, width, height), (a coordinate within 'start'))

def grabGame():
    #The coordinates of the entire game window
    x1 = 2222
    y1 = 320
    x2 = 2850 
    y2 = 1105

    #The entire screen of the game
    window = ig.grab(bbox = (x1, y1, x2, y2))
    window = io.grayscale(window)

    return window

grabStart(grabGame())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `pyautogui.locate()`. Function takes in input two parameter's, the first is the image which needs to be found, the second one is the image in which the smaller image needs to be found. This method only works for images, so if you want to run this for a live window, you might consider another option. Secondly `pyautogui` is just a wrapper over `PIL` so if you run into efficiency issues, you might wanna translate the `locate()` into its PIL equivalent for performance.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way of doing it. I just leave the program running and open/close and move a preview of the button around the screen seeing if it spots the button and reports the coordinates correctly.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import ImageGrab as ig, Image
import pyautogui as ag

def checkButton(button, window):
    try:
        location = ag.locate(button, window, confidence=0.8)
        print(f'location: {location[0]},{location[1]},{location[2]},{location[3]}')
    except:
        print('Not found')

# Load button just once at startup
button = Image.open("button.png")

# Loop, looking for button
while True:
    window = ig.grab()
    checkButton(button, window)
```

Comment: @VasuDeo.S Thank you for the editing suggestions. I accepted them all except the shebang which I prefer to leave so that it is obvious I am targeting Python3. I hate finding stuff on the Web that is for Python2 and not realising.

Comment: what a shebang? I am not familiar with Linux stuff so please pardon me for that.

Comment: @VasuDeo.S It tells the shell which program to use to run a script. Windows relies on the extension in the filename, but Linux/macOS do not. So, I can write a script with no extension on Linux and it will still know how to run it. Windows ignores shebangs so it is harmless on Windows.

Comment: so on linux you can write a python file with the name `Mark` without a `.py` extension, and just add `#!/usr/bin/env python3` in the beginning of the python file, and the file would be interpreted as a python file by the OS? And what will happen if the file is saved as `Mark.py`? will both produce the same effect?

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer my doubts.^_^